# Pass an additional counter as parameter to a callback

Tags: jquery

I have a `$("").load` call to get data and dump it into several divs. Each div has a unique ID that I track with an index variable inside a For loop. I do several ajax calls inside this loop. In the call back function I want to use the value of this index again. However by the time the callback executes, the for loop is already finished the index variable always has the top limit value for the loop.

How can I pass the value to this index to the callback function?

EDIT:

```
for (var i=1;i<=daysNum;i++)
{


    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + i); 


    var tmd=(tomorrow.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(tomorrow.getDate())+'/'+tomorrow.getFullYear();
    var tmdurl=(tomorrow.getMonth()+1)+'%2F'+(tomorrow.getDate())+'%2F'+tomorrow.getFullYear();

    $("#events").append("<div><div id='event"+i+"'></div><div id='date"+i+"'>"+tmd+"</div></div>");
    $("#event"+i).load(seicalendarurl+"/calendar.aspx?CalendarDate="+tmdurl+"&CalendarPeriod=Day .ms-cal-tdayitem, .ms-cal-alldayevent"

        ,  function (data){
             if($("event"+i).html()=="")
                $("date"+i).html("");

           }
    );

}
```

Comment: Give us some code (not necessarily complete function bodies) that we can work with.

Comment: Create a closure.  (Show the loop and callback code and I'll show what I mean)

Comment: I pasted some of the code. I tried passing the i variable as an extra command, but it gets the value of the status of the request(success)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the entier loop body (or only the Ajax part) into an immediate function and pass the index as parameter:

```
for(var i=1;i<=daysNum;i++) {
    // other stuff
    (function(index) {
        $("#event"+index).load('...', function (){
            if($("#event"+index).html() === "") // you need `#` here too!
                $("#date"+index).empty();       // you need `#` here too!
        });
    }(i));
}
```

But you don't necessarily need the index. You can access the `#eventX` element inside the callback with `this` and the `#dateX` element is the next sibling. So you can simply do

```
for(var i=1;i<=daysNum;i++) {
    // other stuff
    $("#event"+index).load('...', function (){
        if($(this).html() === "") {
            $(this).next().empty();
        } 
    });
}
```

which is much more readable imo.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the load callback function.

You are not missing  the "#" before the event and date element selectors.

Try this version for the load callback:

```
function (data){            
    if($("#event"+i).html()=="")               
        $("#date"+i).html("");           
}
```

Comment: @Felix: may be I am missing something. Wouldn't the right value of variable i be available in the callback (clojure)?

Comment: No, JavaScript has only function scope, not block scope. By the time the callbacks evaluate `i`, the loop already finished and `i` has the value of the last iteration.

Comment: @Felix: Thx. I think I need to get back to understanding clojures in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i<x; i++){
  Ajax(...,function(i) {
    // in callback !
    return function(data) {
      //Work with i:)
    };
  }(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any better way, but you can send index with ajax request with data parameter and then return it with the response in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the div unique index as either the div ID, the div's`.data()` or even in the [metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata). Another option is using closures.